# quick standard deviation with weights

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I wanted to use a function that would quickly give me a standard deviation of a vector ad allow me to include weights for elements in the vector. i.e.

```
sd(c(1,2,3))     #weights all equal 1
#[1] 1
sd(c(1,2,3,3,3))  #weights equal 1,1,3 respectively
#[1] 0.8944272
```

For weighted means I can use `wt.mean()` from `library(SDMTools)` e.g.

```
>  mean(c(1,2,3))
[1] 2
>     wt.mean(c(1,2,3),c(1,1,1))
[1] 2
> 
>     mean(c(1,2,3,3,3))
[1] 2.4
>     wt.mean(c(1,2,3),c(1,1,3))
[1] 2.4
```

but the `wt.sd` function does not seem to provide what I thought I wanted:

```
>   sd(c(1,2,3))
[1] 1
>     wt.sd(c(1,2,3),c(1,1,1))
[1] 1
>     sd(c(1,2,3,3,3))
[1] 0.8944272
>     wt.sd(c(1,2,3),c(1,1,3))
[1] 1.069045
```

I am expecting a function that returns `0.8944272` from me weighted `sd`. Preferably I would be using this on a data.frame like:

```
data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),w=c(1,1,3))
```

Comment: Note the docs from `SDMTools::wt.var`: "wt.var is the unbiased variance of the weighted mean calculation using equations of GNU Scentific Library".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(Hmisc)
sqrt(wtd.var(1:3,c(1,1,3)))
#[1] 0.8944272
```

Answer (score 4):

You can  use `rep` to replicate the values according to their weights. Then, `sd` can be computed for the resulting vector.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3) # values
w <- c(1, 1, 3) # weights

sd(rep(x, w))
[1] 0.8944272
```

Comment: +1 - but have a look at `Hmisc::wtd.var`'s implementation, that looks a lot more scalable.